# Add extra fields in manage customer and edit customer section in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I am using **Magento ver. 1.9.1.0**

So please help me according to the version of magento. I am new in this.

I am facing the problem is that I want to use extra (Lat Long field in) manage customer->add new customer in magento backend, so that user can add latlong of the address(any latlong). Now I have tried the following steps from the website.
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45620/how-to-add-extra-fields-in-registration-form
http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/#instructions

but I can't solve the problem. Somewhere showing extra field for my account in frontend, but I want to use the backend extra field on manage customer as an address and save it.
So if possible please provide me the right way to do and if you have the right tutorial please reply me.
I am trying this from few days but still no luck.

Also I have tried to install some extension from mangeto connect but giving error

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I have done this by the following queries.

```
INSERT INTO  `sta_eav_attribute` (
```

`attribute_id` ,
`entity_type_id` ,
`attribute_code` ,
`attribute_model` ,
`backend_model` ,
`backend_type` ,
`backend_table` ,
`frontend_model` ,
`frontend_input` ,
`frontend_label` ,
`frontend_class` ,
`source_model` ,
`is_required` ,
`is_user_defined` ,
`default_value` ,
`is_unique` ,
`note`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '2',  'latlong', NULL , NULL ,  'varchar', NULL , NULL ,  'text',  'Lat Long', NULL ,  '',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '0',  ''
);

INSERT INTO  `sta_eav_entity_attribute` (
`entity_attribute_id` ,
`entity_type_id` ,
`attribute_set_id` ,
`attribute_group_id` ,
`attribute_id` ,
`sort_order`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '2',  '2',  '2',  'your id max of sta_eav_attribute',  '200'
);

INSERT INTO  `sta_customer_eav_attribute` (
`attribute_id` ,
`is_visible` ,
`input_filter` ,
`multiline_count` ,
`validate_rules` ,
`is_system` ,
`sort_order` ,
`data_model`
)
VALUES (
'your id max of sta_eav_attribute',  '1', NULL ,  '1', NULL ,  '0',  '0', NULL
);

INSERT INTO  `sta_customer_form_attribute` (
`form_code` ,
`attribute_id`
)
VALUES (
'adminhtml_customer_address',  'your id max of sta_eav_attribute'
), (
'customer_address_edit',  'your id max of sta_eav_attribute'
), (
'customer_register_address',  'your id max of sta_eav_attribute'
);